# No sound from CA0132 (Creative Core3D) again!

Tags: drivers, sound, kernel, pulseaudio, hardware

My built-in soundcard is playing games with me ever since I've had it. It's like the 10th time it just decides not to output sound.

To begin with, **proving that it's not a hardware issue**, I plugged in a 16.04 32bit UbuntuMATE & the card's working fine. *I was about to install a windows just to get proof! Headaches!!*

Please tell me how to debug this. I just want to forget that card. Just make it work! I can't really lay my hands on the problem this time. I could do a back-flip if you want.

***Below is some information about the system***

---

## from `aplay -l`:

```
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: CA0132 Analog [CA0132 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: CA0132 Digital [CA0132 Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

## [alsa-info](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24993497/)

## [verbose pulseaudio](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24978632/)

## [hardinfo](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24978556/)

## [hwinfo](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24978562/)

***Kernel:***

---

## `uname -a`:

```
Linux 4sq 4.4.0-75-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:56:33 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

## [Related Issue On bugzilla.kernel.org](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=67071)

## [others issues?](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=ca0132)

***MotherBoard:*** *(bios is up-to-date)*

---

## [G1.Sniper Z87](http://www.gigabyte.us/Motherboard/G1Sniper-Z87-rev-11#kf)

## [Issue with bios setting (launchpad)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1658528)

*what else...*

---

*edit:*

[Output from debug command](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24993525/)

[Output from debug command (the rest)](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24993531/)

`dmesg -t | grep snd`

```
snd_ca0106 0000:05:01.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0001)
snd_ca0106 0000:05:01.0: Model 1004 Rev 00000000 Serial 10041102
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Disabling MSI
snd_hda_intel 0000:01:00.1: Handle vga_switcheroo audio client
snd_hda_intel 0000:00:03.0: failed to add i915 component master (-19)
snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC2D2: autoconfig for CA0132: line_outs=1 (0xb/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:line
snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC2D2:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC2D2:    hp_outs=1 (0x10/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC2D2:    mono: mono_out=0x0
snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC2D2:    dig-out=0xc/0x0
snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC2D2:    inputs:
snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC2D2:      Mic=0x12
snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC2D2:      Line=0x11
usbcore: registered new interface driver snd-usb-audio
snd_ca0106 0000:05:01.0: Writing to ADC failed!
snd_ca0106 0000:05:01.0: Writing to ADC failed!
snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC2D2: ca0132 DSP downloaded and running
snd_hda_codec_ca0132 hdaudioC2D2: ca0132 DSP downloaded and running
snd_ca0106 0000:05:01.0: Writing to ADC failed!
snd_ca0106 0000:05:01.0: Writing to ADC failed!
snd_ca0106 0000:05:01.0: Writing to ADC failed!
snd_ca0106 0000:05:01.0: Writing to ADC failed!
```

[rest of `dmesg -t`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/24993716/)

---

**Edit:** The issue seems to be related to a bios parameter. The results so far are inconsistent. I just try setting the parameter to "auto" or "enabled" and it eventually works. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1658528

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Salutations! in terminal run: 
amixer -c2 set 'IEC958' mute

this tells alsamixer to
adjust the correct card which is card 2 shown by aplay -l, or is it card 0 ! and you need to mute 'IEC958'

## #

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure

Comment: salut! I've done what you've told me and added the outputs above

Comment: At this point i would try with a few different kernels , try the liquorix kernel, which am currently running:  Linux tru 4.11.0-8.1-liquorix-amd64 https://liquorix.net/, and an upstream kernel i'd test from kernel 4.10 to 12 see: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/KernelMainlineBuilds . to install  the liquorix kernel , gcc 6 is rquried see: https://gist.github.com/application2000/73fd6f4bf1be6600a2cf9f56315a2d91

Comment: run pavucontrol  ->output devices and select the built in card Click "set as fallback" button to set it as default device, check "mute" button state, increase volume using the fader. you can also run and use alsamixer , apt install alsamixer: run $ alsamixer , Press F6 , select the second device use arrow keys to highlight the 2nd device then press enter key) .Use left/right arrows key to move around faders, up/down arrows to increase volume and "m" key to unmute. alays make sure the device is unmute.

Comment: I've edit my original answer , try it!

Comment: thx Sary appreciate all the help

Comment: np! you found it, well done.

Answer (score 0):

This flag was off. Turning it on fixed it.

[image]